# Colocar em negrito o title de um span

Tags: html5, css3

Olá,

estou precisando colocar o texto do meu title em negrito.

```
<span title="teste">teste</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
<span class="teste" title="teste">teste</span>

.teste {
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Boa sorte.